# Doesn't return <li> from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I simply want to render li to ul(an ordered list) from an array but for some reason it doesn't work for me. This shows an error `Map is not a function` when I map through the array. Any help would greatly be appreciated

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

class List extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      list: [<li>Default-li</li>]
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className='global'>

        <button onClick={() => {
          this.setState({ list: this.state.list.push(<li>Added-li</li>) })
          console.log(this.state.list.length);
        }
        }>ADD</button>

        <ul>
          {
            this.state.list.map((li) => {
              return (li);
            })
          }
        </ul>

      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default List;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get it because in the first `render` the `list` is not populated yet.
Try to conditionally render it:

```
this.state.list && this.state.list.map((li) => {
              return (li);
            })
```

Another issue is with your `setState`, it's adviced to use the functional version of setState and access the `list` within the parameter of it (i'm also using ES6 spread syntax instead of pushing and mutating the array ):

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ list: [...prevState.list, <li>Added-li</li>] }))
```

Running example:

```js
class List extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      list: [<li>Default-li</li>]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="global">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState(prevState => ({ list: [...prevState.list, <li>Added-li</li>] }))
            console.log(this.state.list.length);
          }}
        >
          ADD
        </button>

        <ul>
          {this.state.list &&
            this.state.list.map(li => {
              return li;
            })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment,
The functional version of `setState` was not the issue here but it is better to use because `setState` batches the updates and you may not have the current updated state that you expect.
With the functional `setState` version, you guaranty to get the current "version" of the state.
You can read more about it in the [DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate).

The real issue here was that you used [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) which is not returning the array but the [new length of it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value) (it will mutate the original array which is considered as bad practice as well).

This is why i used the ES6 [array spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) which allow us to create a shallow copy for a new array and combine it with a new value.

Comment: just saw your update to the question, i was off with my answer. now i fixed it.

Comment: What is not working exactly?  The snippet i provided works as expected though

Comment: I'm impressed with your code. can you spare a moment to explain how prevState work there, and is it a default function.

Comment: No problem, glad i could belp

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs... the Array.prototype.push() of JavaScript does not return a new array but the length of the new array... I'll suggest you change your function to be

```
       <button onClick={() => {
          let list = this.state.list
          list.push(<li>Added-li</li>)
          this.setState({ list })
          console.log(this.state.list.length);
        }
        }>ADD</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'; 

class List extends React.Component {

constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
        list:["Default-li"]
    }
}

render() {

    return(
        <div className = 'global'>

            <button onClick = { () => {
            this.state.list = Object.assign([],this.state.list,this.state.list.push("a"))
                            {console.log(this.state.list)}
                            this.forceUpdate()
            }
            }>ADD</button>

            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.list.map((li) =>{
                                              return(<li>{li}</li>)
                    })
                }
            </ul>

        </div>
    );
}
}

export default List;
```

verified. You can try it 
as the type of this.state object is always object so we just need to make it array 
hope this help 
it is working on my pc hope it work for you to.